# canvasengine Tiled_server Error: ENOENT, open './map.json'

Tags: node.js, canvasengine

This is my problem:
I try start Canvasengine example server and I get this error.

```
root@vps185158:/# node /var/www/canvas/canvasengine/examples/tiled_server/server/server.js
   info  - socket.io started
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized ogjRNMePBqcD_ZIkFVFK
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/ogjRNMePBqcD_ZIkFVFK
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client ogjRNMePBqcD_ZIkFVFK
   debug - client authorized for
   debug - websocket writing 1::
/node_modules/canvasengine/core/engine-common.js:373
                        if (err) throw err;
                                       ^
Error: ENOENT, open './map.json'
    at Error (native)
```

map.json is there, but nodejs can't find that file.

Server have Debian 7, nodejs, Socket.io and CanvasEngine 1.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code, you should either copy `map.json` to your working directory (which seems to be `/`, so I wouldn't necessarily recommend that) or start the server from its respective directory:

```
$ cd /var/www/canvas/canvasengine/examples/tiled_server/server/
$ node server
```

(although this may require setting `$NODE_PATH`)